# CSS Media Queries for responsive design

Tags: css, media-queries

I have done with my HTML website and completed responsive design using CSS media queries. Now if i made any changes in any devices means it is affecting another device view. So can anyone provide me a correct order of media queries to resolve my issue. I have mentioned my CSS media query code below.

```css
/*Responsive CSS*/
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1280px) { }

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1281px) and (max-device-width : 1380px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { }

/* iPad (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { }

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 411px) and (max-device-width : 823px) and (orientation: landscape) { }

/* iPad (Portrait & landscape) ----------- */
@media (max-width: 1024px) { }

/*Mobile Phones*/
@media (max-width: 767px) { }

/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) { }

/* Samsung Galaxy Note 3 */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (min-device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait) {}

/* ----------- Galaxy S3 ----------- */
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (min-device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) { }

/* ----------- iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+ ----------- */
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait) { }

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1024px) and (max-device-width : 1380px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {}

/* iPad Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1023px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { }

/* ----------- iPhone X ----------- */ 
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 812px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape) { }

/* ----------- Galaxy S4, S5 and Note 3 ----------- */ 
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape) {}

/* ----------- Galaxy S3 ----------- */
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) { }

/* ----------- iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+ ----------- */
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape) { }

/* ----------- iPhone 6, 6S, 7 and 8 ----------- */
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) { }

/* ----------- iPhone 5, 5S, 5C and 5SE ----------- */
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) {}

/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */ 
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) {}
```

Comment: You cannot target exact devices with media queries like that, you should just target general sizes and make sure that it looks nice in all devices around that size

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "_correct order_" _ As far as I know there is no priority of one set of @media rules over another_ the page simply responds to the pertinent set of CSS directives _ The previous contributor is essentially correct about not having so many sets of media queries_ not least because wherever the dimensions coincide / overlap the results on the page will become unpredictable _ This is probably one of those occasions when the phrase 'Less is More' might apply

Answer (score 0):

Make general media queries instead of exact queries for all kinds of devices.

This always helps out [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp), I'd suggest looking here just to get an idea/experiment with it first before you target all your elements.